How to edit data from List in table Thymeleaf
I pass List to model. Use th:each="userDTO : ${usersDTO}" then <form th:object="${userDTO}" to edit data directly in table th:field="*{firstName} . This doesn't work, although if I replace th:field with th:value then the data is displayed correctly.
ParseException and
IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userDTO' available as request attribute
         <td th:text="${userDTO.id}"></td>
         <td><input type="text" id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}"></td>
         <td><input type="text" id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}"></td>
         <td><input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}"></td>

           <td>
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
           </td>
  </form>





                <td th:text="${userDTO.id}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}"></td>
                <td><input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}"></td>


In Thymeleaf, the th:field is used to bind data with model object fields. Be sure that object fields are correct like as following thymeleaf notations.
<form th:action="@{/submit}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
 label for="name">Name:</label>
 <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name" />

 <label for="email">Email:</label>
 <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" id="email" />

 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

be ensure that you use the correct binding
@PostMapping("/submit")
public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("formObject") FormObject formObject, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "form";
    }
    // process form data
    return "success";
}


I get List from controller and want to change fields in table. So i use th:each="userDTO : ${usersDTO}  and than <form th:object="${userDTO}> and then  

edited above, please check last part of my response
